# apex column dynamic loaded chart remove last selection of columns when update new series

Tags: angular, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

I'm using [ng-apexcharts](/questions/tagged/ng-apexcharts) and I want to remove last selection of column on update of chart.

In this example https://apexcharts.com/angular-chart-demos/column-charts/dynamic-loaded-chart once select Quarterly Results its become selected and color change with dark one.

Once change selection from **Yearly Results chart** series is changed in **Quarterly Results chart** but selection is not removed.

Tried with this solution to update selection but its not working.

```
return window.ApexCharts.exec(destChartIDToUpdate, "updateOptions", {
    chart: {
      selection: {
        xaxis: {
          min: undefined,
          max: undefined
        }
      }
    },
    series: series,
    colors: colors,
    fill: {
      colors: colors
    }
  });
```

[image: On selection of any other year from Yearly Results chart Q2 Must be Un-Selected In Quarterly]